# Is there any verb net project in Japanese?

Tags: verbs, japanese, verb-phrase

I'm looking for a verb network or verb dictionary project in Japanese which shows verbs with  its own dependencies (like [iku DP DP] [kaeru DP] etc.). Is there any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Japanese word net may contain useful data: http://compling.hss.ntu.edu.sg/wnja/